# How to place turtles with mouse based on who number?

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to recreate the bubble shooter game where there are color bubbles in rows that you pop by angling bubbles of the same color in that direction using the mouse. However, since I am using turtles as the bubbles, when I create more than 2 to shoot, the turtles do not shoot in the order of their who number and I can't tell what color I'm using unless I use inspect.

I tried to use foreach to ask each turtle to list their colors into a list that is displayed and organize them to be shot in the order of their who numbers. I was able to sort them into a list based on their who numbers to display their colors, but I can't order them to be shot out in the correct order.

Here is my code so far:

```
 ;creates the bubbles to be shot
 set list1 []
   cro 10
     [set color one-of [red green blue violet]
      setxy 0 -12
      set size 3
      set shape "circle"]
  foreach sort-on [who] turtles with [who >= 80] with [who <= 99]
   [the-turtles -> ask the-turtles [set list1 lput [color] of self list1]]
    user-message "The list in the command center shows the colors of the 
    bubbles listed here in consecutive order. Refer to the note on the side 
    of the screen for refernce. Click game1 to angle and fire"
  show list1

   to game1
   ;creates the launcher from which turtles are fired from
   ask turtle 1 [face (patch mouse-xcor mouse-ycor)]
   ;moves the bubbles to the target
   foreach sort-on [who] turtles with [size = 3]
    [the-turtles -> ask the-turtles [
     if mouse-down? [ask the-turtles [wait .1 move-to patch mouse-xcor 
      mouse-ycor
     if count turtles in-radius 4 with [color = [color] of self] with [size 
      = 4] >= 3
     [ask turtles in-radius 2 with [color = [color] of self] with [size >= 
      3] [die]]]]]]  
     end
     ;size 3 is the size of the turtles I'm firing with the mouse
     ;size 4 is the size of the rows of turtles that will be "popped"
```

Instead of outputting the turtles shot in the order of their who number, the turtles are ordered randomly in comparison to my ordered list1. Any advice is appreciated thank you!